# What is the SHA256 that comes on the sshd entry in auth.log?

Tags: ssh, logging

When logging in via ssh, it can be seen the following on auth.log:

```
Dec 14 16:29:30 app sshd[22781]: Accepted publickey for dev from XXX.XXX.XX.XXX port XXXXX ssh2: RSA SHA256:pO8i...
```

I've been trying to figure out what is this SHA256 information, but I couldn't find anything that seems to match. First I thought it could be some information from the client (public key, fingerprint, hashed hostname etc) I'm connecting from, but I didn't find anything to confirm, neither at the server side.

The closest information I've found is [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Logging_and_Troubleshooting), but I didn't understand when it says "And here is an example using a key for authentication. It shows the kewy (a misspelling, probably) fingerprint as a SHA256 hash in base64.", since I haven't found a corresponding key fingerprint of any kind.

Thank you.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is the `SHA256` hash for the RSA public key which was used to authenticate the SSH session.

This is how to verify it:

```
ssh-keygen -lf .ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Or, to verify without `ssh-keygen`:

- Remove the `ssh-rsa` prefix
- Decode the key to bytes using `base64`
- Get the `SHA256` hash for the key (as bytes, not hex)
- Encode the bytes using `base64`

For example:

```
cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub    |
    awk '{ print $2 }' | # Only the actual key data without prefix or comments
    base64 -d          | # decode as base64
    sha256sum          | # SHA256 hash (returns hex)
    awk '{ print $1 }' | # only the hex data
    xxd -r -p          | # hex to bytes
    base64               # encode as base64
```

Comment: It turns out that you can use `ssh-keygen -lf .ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Comment: I think your comment is a separate and all-round better answer, which you should add separately.

Comment: +1 to adding `ssh-keygen -lf .ssh/id_rsa.pub` as a separate answer.  It is better then manual encoding.

Comment: Just an additional information: the same command works well with authorized_keys:

*ssh-keygen -lf .ssh/authorized_keys*

Answer (score 4):

Had the same question on macOS 10.13.6, where your answer just needed a couple of tweaks:

```
cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub    |
    awk '{ print $2 }' | # Only the actual key data without prefix or comments
    base64 -D          | # decode as base64
    shasum -a 256      | # SHA256 hash (returns hex)
    awk '{ print $1 }' | # only the hex data
    xxd -r -p          | # hex to bytes
    base64               # encode as base64
```

Thanks v. much.